# What is the flow of execution in the BotBuilder-Samples' 'CreateNewConversationBot'?

Tags: botframework

One for Ezequiel Jadib I suspect!

I'm trying to figure out how the above sample fits together, but it has me beaten.

This is my understanding of it. I apologise - there's a lot here. But I'm certain I'm not alone trying to understand all the different ways the BotFramework SDK handles incoming messages.

1. The root container is built. The DialogModule is added, to allow lifetime scopes for each dialog instance. The ResumptionCookie is registered accordingly per dialog lifetime scope. The SurveyModule is then added, which establishes the SurveyScheduler as a singleton, the CreateNewConversationDialog as per-dependency, and the SurveyService as per dialog (DialogModule.LifetimeScopeTag.) Both SurveyService and SurveyScheduler are mysteriously `.Keyed<ISurvey...>(FiberModule.Key_DoNotSerialize)`, which I am unsure about, but *think* is to do with the fact that certain referenced members of those objects are not serializable?

So, anyway: every CreateNewConversationDialog has its own SurveyService when instantiated.

2. Our MessagesController is where everything starts. It takes an ILifetimeScope parameter, which (as I have recently learned, thanks :) ) is provided automatically by Autofac. Question: is this ILifetimeScope the root container - i.e. the same ILifetimeScope as referred to in SurveyTriggerer, the GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver?
3. In MessageController's Post method, an IPostToBot is resolved in a new dialog lifetime scope, and the incoming message sent there. Does this automatically find the last dialog used? The first time, it must surely find CreateNewConversationDialog, but how does this happen? Does the invocation of DialogModule.BeginLifetimeScope() actually implicitly resolve an IDialog to a CreateNewConversationDialog, as registered in SurveyModule? And where does IPostToBot fit into this? Is the reason we're not using Conversation.SendAsync() that we don't know if we're currently in SurveyDialog or CreateNewConversationDialog?
4. Assuming we're in CreateNewConversationDialog, it simply loops on each message received, calling its own SurveyService's QueueSurveyAsync() with its own resumption cookie, adding the cookie to the singleton's concurrent queue.

Question: why have a SurveyService at all? Why not have a reference to SurveyScheduler and its own ResumptionCookie in CreateNewConversationDialog itself?

5. The SurveyScheduler singleton's BackgroundWorkItem continually polls its queue, and uses SurveyTriggerer's static StartSurvey() method to pop a SurveyDialog on the stack, extracted via the ResumptionCookie. (This is the relatively understandable part!)

Thanks for reading anyway, and I'd be grateful for any clarifications.

Note: I see that this sample isn't supported on all channels, so I'm tempted instead to mimic a 'new direct conversation' just by taking the approach in ContosoFlowers where it returns from the CheckoutController - instead use Conversation.ResumeAsync() and let the calling dialog call a child dialog itself if it wants. Is this a crazy idea?

Comment: Think of all those sweet StackOverflow points! :) Thanks, I appreciate it - it's the combination of the Autofac extensions in the BotFramework itself and trying to learn BotFramework at the same time that makes things less clear than I'd like them to be.

Comment: Might the downvoter care to explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Came up with something (though some answers could be much much longer as some of the topics are too broad).

1. The `FiberModule.Key_DoNotSerialize` key is mainly used to instruct the BotBuilder to recover the object instance, keyed by object type, from the container on deserialization instead of from the serialized object. [This thread](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/1498) might help.
2. They are not the same; the ILifetimeScope in the controller is a
   child scope of the container in
   GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver.
3. **Short answer**: we are not using Conversation.SendAsync because that will imply creating the dialog manually and we want to use DI as dialogs have dependencies that needs to be resolved. **Long answer**: [IPostToBot](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/ConnectorEx/PostToBot.cs#L52) is the interface the contains the method to send a message from the user to the bot. There are tons of implementations of this interface in the BotBuilder library, and there is a [chain of these registered in the AutoFac container](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Autofac/Dialogs/DialogModule.cs#L307-L316). The incoming message flows through the chain until the last one ([the PersistentDialogTask](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/Dialogs/DialogTask.cs)), which does a lot of black magic :), like using an [ScoringEventLoop](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/Dialogs/ScoringEventLoop.cs) to dispatch the incoming activities to a scorable action; and if the scorable action does not match, it will go to the [dialog system](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/3a98a6b3d15962a57b5454bfb3f730d3588de3ef/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/Dialogs/DialogSystem.cs#L54). You asked :). Best way to understand this; is to download the code of the BotBuilder library; hook it into a Bot and start debugging.
4. Yes, it could be simplified as you are suggesting. The sample was based on the [AlarmBot sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/tree/master/CSharp/Samples/AlarmBot) so we kept a lot of the pieces there.
5. Yes. And to create a direct conversation between the bot and the user. If the channel supports direct conversation (e.g. Slack), if you are talking with the Bot in an multiple users channel, it will kick off the survey in a private conversation.

One of the purposes of the sample is to show how to proactively message the user based on eternal events. [Here](http://github.com/Microsoftdx/botFramework-proactiveMessages) are some simpler examples around proactive message that you will find useful I think.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. There certainly is a lot of black magic behind the scenes, I agree with you there! Last counter-comment: in 3), it seems that using IPostToBot is the most generic way of sending the message. Is the reason we can't use `Conversation.SendAsync(() => scope.Resolve<StartNewConversationDialog>());` that the SurveyDialog isn't a direct child dialog of StartNewConversationDialog? i.e. it was added to the stack outside of StartNewConversationDialog? Thanks.

Comment: Those extra samples are handy too, ta.

Comment: Actually, I think that with the latest updated we did, you should be able to use Conversation.SendAsync... but you still need to do that inside the "using (var scope = DialogModule.BeginLifetimeScope(this.scope, activity))" otherwise it won't work as some of the services won't be found in the scope received in the constructor.

Comment: Confirmed, I tried it (before I even noticed your update actually!) and it worked correctly,